# Is it possible to save custom data between sessions in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on extending an Eclipse plugin (one which opens a new Eclipse IDE). The plugin produces a table (treeview) which is restored when the plugin is closed and opened again.

Now my extension of this plugin uses the data from this table to generate it's own data (which is not displayed in an Eclipse view). I wonder if it is possible to save my data (just a map of maps of basic data types) the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to save data is to use the 'state location' directory for your plugin. This is a directory in the workspace meta data which is entirely under the control of your plugin.

Get the directory path using:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

IPath stateLoc = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

You can put anything you like in this location.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this!